# Stitching 360 panorama with OpenCv

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I tried to implement stitching 360 panorama image using opencv inside ios app (also we tried such code in android app). I have implemented yet simple stitch method from Stitcher class. But when I trying to set more than 8 images ios system killed app because of incorrect memory using (out of memory error in android).  Please can somebody give the advise how I can create 360 panorama image?
I use such code:

```
Mat result;    
Ptr<Stitcher> stitcher = Stitcher::create(Stitcher::PANORAMA, true);
// images that's array of Mat
Stitcher::Status status = stitcher -> stitch(images, result);
```

Also I tried [this method](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp)

But I have the same result.

Comment: How many images you want to combined in order to create the full 360 panaroma

Comment: Depends on position in apartment, but usually about 8-10 images

Comment: And approximate size (width, height) of each image ?

Comment: @ZdaR the size of the image is 4096 × 2304 pixel